# Magento Default one page checkout Not Working - Jquery Conflict

Tags: php, magento, billing, opc

I have configure two Magento stores on one installation. In these two, primary store one page checkout not working fine [ Actually it does not move to next step - billing step ] in step2.

When view the source via browser it does not require billing.html file

Is there any solution for this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nApzp.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if jquery is conflicting with prototype as this is a problem when all prototype functions doesnt work

use noConflict for that

Good news getting jQuery included in magento 2.0 :)

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt couple of times with such a problem and nine out of ten times it is caused by a misbehaving shipping or payment module. I suggest you to disable all non-default modules and retry and see what happens.

I would try this after you have walked through default Magento debugging procedure.